# How to format inputted data and output it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking to creat a  code which asks for input and then  add data to a tab delimated file in the output form of say :

```
      Author.Year.Title.Journal
```

But I also need to format the input in a way that if there are two authors the out put 
will be :

```
 Author1 &Author2.year.title.journal
```

and if they are 3 authors the output will be

```
 Author1,Author2&Author3. year. title. journal
```

here is my code so far :

```
try:
    import csv     
    file = raw_input('Enter Filename:')
    with open(file,'a') as openfile:
      writer = csv.writer(openfile,delimiter='.')
      ans=True
      while ans:
        print ("""
        1.
        2.
        3
        """)
       ans = raw_input("How Many Authors?")
       if ans=="1":
         author = raw_input('Enter Author Name:')
         title = raw_input('Enter Title Name:')
         year= raw_input('Enter year:')
         journal = raw_input('Enter Journal:')
         writer.writerow([author,title,year,journal])

      elif ans=="2":
           auhtor_1 = raw_input('Enter First Author''s Name:')
           author_2 = raw_input('Enter Second Author''s Name:')
           title = raw_input('Enter Title Name:')
           year= raw_input('Enter year:')
           journal = raw_input('Enter Journal:')

      elif ans=="3":
           auhtor_1 = raw_input('Enter First Author''s Name:')
           author_2 = raw_input('Enter Second Author''s Name:')
           author_3 = raw_input('Enter Third Author''s Name:')
           title = raw_input('Enter Title Name:')
           year= raw_input('Enter year:')
           journal = raw_input('Enter Journal:')

except IOError:
    print 'Sorry Something went Wrong'
```

This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: What happens if there are 4 authors? Why not just have an author string which admits any number of authors ? Your code is pointlessly repetitious.

Comment: You mean you don't know how to combine the various fields into one string?

Comment: @JohnColeman if you dont understand my question .. dont come on here and start saying it's pointless ... this is what i was asked to

Comment: @Newbie3005 The *question* wasn't pointless (I'm sorry if you interpreted it that way) but rather the repetition of the raw_input lines is what was pointless. I suspect that you copy-pasted much of that code (hence the tell-tale echoed typo in the variable name for the first author). Whenever you find yourself copy-pasting whole blocks of code -- see about reorganizing it to reduce the repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list to store the author names.

```
authors = []
num_authors = int(raw_input("How Many Authors? "))
for i in range(num_authors):
    authors.append(raw_input("Enter Author's Name ({}): ".format(i+1)))
```

Apart from handling an arbitrary number of authors, a list of authors is generally more useful than a formatted string of authors; e.g. it's easy to determine the number of authors, to sort the authors, or to output the list with different formatting.

To achieve your desired output you can add punctuation using `str.join()`:

```
authors_string = ' & '.join([', '.join(authors[:-1]), authors[-1]]
                                if len(authors) > 2 else authors)
```

The inner `str.join()` joins with commas all authors except the last one or, if there are fewer than 2 authors, no join takes place. The outer join adds the ampersand between the final 2 authors if required.